# Why BufferedWriter here is not writing to the file even though I close it in the end?

Tags: java, printwriter, bufferedwriter

So I have written this class that writes strings to the file in a "for" loop, but I am unable to write the string content to file using either BufferedWriter or PrintWriter in Java. The file gets created in a local directory, but nothing gets written to the file. What seems to be causing the trouble here?

- I have closed/flushed the BufferedWriter/PrintWriter in the end
- The content to be written to file gets printed on the screen but is not written to the file.
- The command "appends" to the file and not "write" (However, I already tried with a write function, but it did not work.)

The code is,

```
package pmidtomeshConverter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Convert2MeSH {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {


    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("pathToALocalDirectory/pmidMESH.txt", true));
    writer.write("at least this writes"); // This does not write either


    JSONObject jsonPMIDlist = readJsonFromUrl("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=Physiotherapy%5d+OR+Rehabilitation");
    JSONArray pmids = new JSONArray();
    pmids = jsonPMIDlist.getJSONObject("esearchresult").getJSONArray("idlist");

    for(int i=0; i<pmids.length();i++){

        String baseURL = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract&id=";

        String indPMID = pmids.get(i).toString();

        Document doc = parseXML(new URL(baseURL + indPMID));

        String xmlString = xml2String(doc);

        // Converts the XML string into JSON
        JSONObject jsonWithMeSH = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

        JSONObject ind_MeSH = jsonWithMeSH.getJSONObject("PubmedArticleSet").getJSONObject("PubmedArticle").getJSONObject("MedlineCitation");

        List<String> list_MeSH = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (ind_MeSH.has("MeshHeadingList")) {

            for (int j = 0; j < ind_MeSH.getJSONObject("MeshHeadingList").getJSONArray("MeshHeading").length(); j++) {

                list_MeSH.add(ind_MeSH.getJSONObject("MeshHeadingList").getJSONArray("MeshHeading").getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("DescriptorName").get("content").toString());
            }

        } else {

            list_MeSH.add("null");

        }

        System.out.println(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH));
        writer.append(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH)); // This does not write to the file either

    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}

private static String xml2String(Document doc) throws TransformerException {

    TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString(2));

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement());

    trans.transform(source, result);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();
    return xmlString;

}

private static Document parseXML(URL url) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse((url).openStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc;
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

The output of the "System.out.println(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH));" is,

- 30541041:null
- 30541034:null
- 30541029:null
- 30541003:null
- 30540990:null
- 30540822:null
- 30540806:null
- ...

Comment: It seems like it will write to the file for me, or is your question why does it not write on a new line? Your code now will just write everything on one line

Comment: My question is "Why doesn't it write anything to the file at all?" It literally does not write anything to the file. It did not even write the line " writer.write("at least this writes");" even though it is directly after I declare the BufferedWriter.

Comment: I was in the understanding that it did print `"at least this writes"`, which was wrong. Does it throw any errors? Does it have write permission to that directory/file? It seems to work for me just fine

Comment: Yes, it has write permission to the directories since I am the admin. I get a blank file even after 500 iterations of printing. It did the job yesterday, but today it acts strange.

Comment: You don't get any errors ?

Comment: Stupid question, but are you looking at the correct file? I've had it happen too many times that I was looking at the wrong file, expecting something to be printed there while it was writing to another file. What if you close and open the file in your text editor?

Comment: @dglozano No, I do not get any errors. The program works perfectly fine printing the string on console but writing nothing to the file after creating it.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I mention just one directory/file in the script. The file is created in the mentioned location, but nothing gets written. Not even a newline or space for that matter.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out everything after `writer.write("at least this writes"); // This does not write either` and test it ? It should work then. If it doesn't, it is a permission related problem, or maybe try deleting the existing file and creating it again. If not, we can check further

Comment: Even restarting eclipse did not work out.

Comment: @dglozano Yes, it does work that way. It writes "at least this writes" after commenting rest of the code.

Comment: Change `writer.append(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH)); ` for `writer.write(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH)); ` . If you already set the append flag to `true` while creating the FileWriter, it the `write` method should append it

Comment: Also, edit your question and post what is the output of this `System.out.println(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH));`

Comment: @dglozano I did the changes. replaced append function with the write function and still I see a blank file.

Comment: Ok I have no idea what it can be. Try deleting the file and let the java program create it.

Comment: Deleted the file while the program was running and I still get no error but see the strings getting printed on the screen. Do not know if it is even writing to any file.

Comment: Put everything between writer.write("at least this writes");  and writer.flush(); writer.close(); in try and catch block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have worked out quite a detour solution. I understand that anything in the for-loop wasn't getting written in the file, and I have no idea why the content was not appended to the file.

The solution: First, in the loop, I write the content to a Hashmap and then outside the for-loop write the Hashmap to the file using serialization. It worked perfectly fine.

Here is the code,

```
package pmidtomeshConverter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;      
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Convert2MeSH {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/anjani/eclipse-workspace/pmidtomeshConverter/src/main/resources/outputFiles/pmidMESH.txt", true));

        //Universal Multimap to store the values
        Map<String, String> universalMeSHMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        FileOutputStream fs;
        BufferedWriter writer;
        try {

            fs = new FileOutputStream("/home/anjani/eclipse-workspace/pmidtomeshConverter/src/main/resources/outputFiles/pmidMESH.txt");
            OutputStreamWriter ow = new OutputStreamWriter(fs);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(ow);

            JSONObject jsonPMIDlist = readJsonFromUrl("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=1000&term=Physiotherapy%5d+OR+Rehabilitation");
            JSONArray pmids = new JSONArray();
            pmids = jsonPMIDlist.getJSONObject("esearchresult").getJSONArray("idlist");

            for(int i=0; i<pmids.length();i++){

                 String baseURL = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&rettype=abstract&id=";
                 String indPMID = pmids.get(i).toString();

                 Document doc = parseXML(new URL(baseURL + indPMID));

                 // Converts xml from doc into a string
                 String xmlString = xml2String(doc);

                // Converts the xml-string into JSON
                JSONObject jsonWithMeSH = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

                JSONObject ind_MeSH = jsonWithMeSH.getJSONObject("PubmedArticleSet").getJSONObject("PubmedArticle").getJSONObject("MedlineCitation");

                List<String> list_MeSH = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (ind_MeSH.has("MeshHeadingList")) {

                for (int j = 0; j < ind_MeSH.getJSONObject("MeshHeadingList").getJSONArray("MeshHeading").length(); j++) {

                    list_MeSH.add(ind_MeSH.getJSONObject("MeshHeadingList").getJSONArray("MeshHeading").getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("DescriptorName").get("content").toString());
                }

                } else {

                list_MeSH.add("null");

                }

            System.out.println(indPMID + ":" + String.join("\t", list_MeSH));

            // instead of writing to a file, the content is stored in a HashMap
            universalMeSHMap.put(indPMID, String.join("\t", list_MeSH));                

        }

        // Writing the HashMap to the file (This is the answer)
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : universalMeSHMap.entrySet()) {

            writer.append(entry.getKey() + ":" +  entry.getValue() + "\n");

        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String xml2String(Document doc) throws TransformerException {

    TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", Integer.toString(2));

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement());

    trans.transform(source, result);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();
    return xmlString;

}

private static Document parseXML(URL url) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse((url).openStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    return doc;
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}}
```

The result file looks this way,

[The content gets written to the file. Each line in the file contains a unique Pubmed ID attached to the MeSH terms of the article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QumuM.png)